# Regex for "replace all after first 2 digits after comma"

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I would like to replace all characters after the first 2 digits after a comma.

E.g. having a string of `1234,56789` should result into `1234,56`.

Using `[^,]*$` has led me to the right path, but deleting everything after the comma.

A `[^,]..$` doesnt give me a correct result too, thus I need a way to tell my expression that "the first 2 digits after the comma" got to be deleted, not "the last 2 digits" since thats what the ".." seems to do in my expression.

Comment: If you provide the environment/programming language, it will be possible to provide you with an exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(,\d{2}).*
```

The regex matches and *captures into Group 1* a comma and two digits, and just matches the rest of the line with `.*`.

To remove only after last comma:

```
(.*,\d{2}).*
```

Here, `.*` at the start captures also everything at the start of the string.

A more retrictive pattern will be

```
^(\d+,\d{2})\d*$
```

It matches start of string (with `^`), then one or more digits (with `\d+`), a comma, two digits, all captured into Group 1, and then just  matches zero or more digits (with `\d*`) at the end of the string (`$`).

Replace with `$1` (or `\1` depending on the regex engine). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UjwgEB/1) (also [this one](https://regex101.com/r/UjwgEB/2) and [this one, too](https://regex101.com/r/UjwgEB/3)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import re
re.sub(r',(\d{2}).*', r',\1', a)
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to aid in comprehension.